# Where do you put your MySQL connection credentials in Java

Tags: java, mysql, connection, credentials

I have successfully established a connection to the MySQL db but all the credentials are in the .java connection file. how do I create another file like a settings file and connect the data?

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://path";
    String username = "xxx";
    String password = "yyy";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

    // Step 3: create statement object
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    // Step 4: execute the query
    String sql = "select * from employee";
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    while(resultSet.next()){
        System.out.println(
                "Id: "+ resultSet.getInt(1)+
                ", Name: "+ resultSet.getString(2)+
                ", Email: "+ resultSet.getString(3));
    }

    // Step 5: close the connection
    connection.close();
```

Comment: I would recommend reading the credentials from environment variables, as is suggested by the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/config).

Comment: I opted for using properties file and accessing it through ResourceBundler.   If that doesn't work then you can use FileInputStream .